# How to check accessToken valid if facebook has been logout?

Tags: android, facebook

Here's my scenario,

1. log in facebook in android app, and store the access token to be used next time.
2. change my facebook password.
3. use my app again --> test facebook.isSessionValid() --> it should return "false", but returns "true".

I looked into the "isSessionValid" implementation, but it just tests "accessExpries".

With this scenario, how do I check if the access token is really valid before I proceed to call the Graph API ?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do that is to make a graph request (for "/me" for example), and check that the request succeeds. There's no other guaranteed method that's strictly client-side.